# How to check if username is same? Json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So i have been trying to write a function that checks if app.account_username and a username in a json array are the same, but I'm just going around in circles.

The json array looks like this

```
{
 "data": {
"id": 32607158,
"with_account": "user1",
"with_account_id": 8483786,
"last_message_preview": "XD",
"message_count": 289,
"messages": [{
  "id": 153359194,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711004
}, {
  "id": 153359270,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711023
}, {
  "id": 153359330,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711044
}, {
  "id": 153359334,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711048
}, {
  "id": 153359386,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711057
}, {
  "id": 153359430,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711065
}, {
  "id": 153359474,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711078
}, {
  "id": 153359522,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711090
}, {
  "id": 153359638,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711106
}],
"done": false,
"page": 2,
"datetime": 1439711387
},
"success": true,
"status": 200
}
```

I'm trying to check if "from" is the same as "app.account_username", Does anyone know how this would be achieved?

Comment: Where is `app.account_username` in the question? Also, it would be nice to show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Have you even trying to parse JSON to object and just compare arrays elements fields to app.account_username?

Comment: app.account_username is equal to the username of the current logged in user and is available in the whole scope. The functions I've written are mostly rubbish

Comment: Very roughly: `for (/* loop through data.messages */) if (message.from == app.account_username) { matches = true; break; }` – have you tried something like this? What problems did you have with it?

Comment: can you put your codes which are parsing(if you do) and checking place

Comment: @AngusMckay, you should add your code regardless of whether it's rubbish or not. You might be very close and not know it and we can point you in the right direction. We all had to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse this json string to object and iterate over its array to check every item with **app.account_username**

```
var text = '{  "data": { "id": 32607158, "with_account": "user1", "with_account_id": 8483786, "last_message_preview": "XD", "message_count": 289, "messages": [{   "id": 153359194,   "from": "user1",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 8483786,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711004 }, {   "id": 153359270,   "from": "user2",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 20094939,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711023 }, {   "id": 153359330,   "from": "user1",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 8483786,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711044 }, {   "id": 153359334,   "from": "user2",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 20094939,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711048 }, {   "id": 153359386,   "from": "user1",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 8483786,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711057 }, {   "id": 153359430,   "from": "user2",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 20094939,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711065 }, {   "id": 153359474,   "from": "user1",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 8483786,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711078 }, {   "id": 153359522,   "from": "user2",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 20094939,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711090 }, {   "id": 153359638,   "from": "user2",   "account_id": 20094939,   "sender_id": 8483786,   "body": "*hugs*",   "conversation_id": 32607158,   "datetime": 1439711106 }], "done": false, "page": 2, "datetime": 1439711387 }, "success": true, "status": 200 }';

var obj = JSON.parse( text );


for(var i = 0; i < obj.data.messages.length; i++) 
{
    if(obj.data.messages[i].from == app.account_username)
        {
            doSomething();
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, That looks like it should work. Its stuff like "var i = 0; i < obj.data.messages.length; i++" that i'm still trying to get my head around in  js

Comment: I'm getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" on the line "var obj = JSON.parse(text);" my code looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/xLe9g22d/ I have console log out response.data and it does return the Json array, any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that **response.data** is not valid json - try to log it and check are brackets etc valid

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/shashimj/bdnj09re/)

it displays user1,user2 like that..

```
var test = "your json data"
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
alert(JSON.stringify(test.data.messages[i].from));
```